# Table of contents does not show in a frame

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

In the following presentation, the table of contents does not show on the second slide, but when I change the whole thing to an article (removing beamer related stuff), the table of contents is shown.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\title{Title}  
\author{HaskellElephant}
\date{\today} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{description of problem}
\section{Second Section}
  \subsection{sub1}
  \subsection{sub2}
  \subsection*{sub3}
\section{conclusion}
\end{document}
```

The whole thing is compiled (twice) on the texlive distribution from ubuntu 11.10.

How do I make the table of contents show up on the second slide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example needs something to show and since you have only structural references but no actual frames there is no output shown. Compile the following two times.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\title{Title}  
\author{HaskellElephant}
\date{\today} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{description of problem}
\section{Second Section}
  \subsection{sub1}
  \subsection{sub2}
  \subsection*{sub3}
\section{conclusion}
\frame{dummy frame}
\end{document}
```

and table of contents returns.

Comment: ''Compile the following two times" helped me as well.

Answer (score 3):

In presentation mode the commands `\section` and `\subsection` don't produce text, so the table of contents is not compiled.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\title{Title}  
\author{HaskellElephant}
\date{\today} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{description of problem}
\begin{frame}
desc
\end{frame}
\section{Second Section}
  \subsection{sub1}
\begin{frame}
sub1
\end{frame}
  \subsection{sub2}
\begin{frame}
sub2
\end{frame}
  \subsection*{sub3}
\begin{frame}
sub3
\end{frame}
\section{conclusion}
\begin{frame}
concl
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it wasn't really the kind of answer I wanted. I really just wanted the table of contents to show up.